# Where can I get the Eclipse-GUI code?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

Visiting the CeBit IT-fair in Hannover,Germany I came across two or three applications that were based on the Eclipse GUI (for example  [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio)).
Does anyone know wether the Eclipse GUI is available to the public and if yes, how to get easiest access to it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question. I am a complete noob, currently building my first swing application in java ... I found this was an exciting idea (to get inside into a more complex GUI like eclipse has)

Comment: @codeMan: Possibly Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP) development.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yeah, I had thought of that. I see that others have answered by the time I got back to this one. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are talking about the Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP), which lets you create applications based on Eclipse.

Have a look here for more info and tutorials: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform

Comment: Stupid question, amazing answer! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You need to look into Eclipse plugins.  There's a tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

I would highly recommend you get a detailed book as there are a lot of interesting pitfalls with developing an entire application on eclipse that you don't want to fall into.

Answer (score 0):

The source code to Eclipse is included as a part of [Eclipse for RCP and RAP developer](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junosr2)s.

The Java JAR files in the plugins directory with the word "source" in the file name are source code jar files.